# Runtime Error for 'COOMILK' on CodeChef (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

Hi I am new to Python programming as well as here. I am practicing on www.codechef.com but I am not able to find the solution for the error on my code.

I am using Python 3.4, I am trying to solve this problem https://www.codechef.com/problems/COOMILK

While my code is running perfectly on IDLE it is giving a runtime error when I am trying to submit my code. I tried all the searches and first fixed the **EOFerror** which I was getting on compilation but now I am not able to fix this Runtime error.

```
T = int(input())
for loop in range(T):
failed = False
N = int(input())
activities = input().split()
for check in range(N):
       if len(activities)==1 and activities[check]== 'cookie':
          print ("NO")
          failed = True
       elif activities[check] == 'cookie' and activities[check+1]!= 'milk':
          print ("NO")
          failed = True
if not failed:
       print("YES")
```

It would be great if someone help me out in finding out the problem, I have already checked the code with providing the input as required and it is giving desired output but somehow is giving runtime error on submission.

I will appreciate suggestions on improving my code.
Thank you :)

Comment: There is an error in your code and you will know if you try Example inputs from the problem page.

Comment: Okay so to get an input by space as a delimiter I fixed the code, yet still I am able to get same output in IDLE for the Example inputs, but I am not able to submit my code. I am getting same Runtime Error.

Comment: what does it output on 1 1 cookie?

Comment: Hi thanks for your support, I have updated my code to support that condition but the problem is I am still getting that error.

Comment: I think that is because it is a runtime error which means its having problem in compilation and I have no idea what is causing it.

Comment: You have applied a quick fix but not solved the root cause of the error. The actual problem is when the value of `check` variable becomes equal to `N-1`,  `activities[check+1]` tries to access an element at an index which is out of bounds.